# Populate table with JSON array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

if been trying for some time, but Im not managing to get JSON data into table. Probably because of my not understanding JSON correctly.

I would like to ask for a bit off assistance :)

```
<?php
$json_string = file_get_contents("https://api.cryptonator.com/api/full/btc-usd");
$array = json_decode($json_string, true);
?>
```

Above is first part

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <thead><tr><th>Timestamp</th></tr></thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach($array[0]['markets'] as $key => $value): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $value['market']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $value['price']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $value['volume']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

Above is second part

I would like to populate table with values Market, Price, Value as shown in table above

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: change this `$array[0]['markets']` to this `$array["ticker"]['markets']`

Comment: So close :) Thanks man!

Comment: Welcome friend.. :)